# View image in full size link with imagecache (Drupal)

Tags: drupal

The solution to my problem is probably quite simple, but I can't find it.
I want a link under the images saying "view full size" that links to the original, full-sized picture. I've only find the $imagecache_path variable that prints the path to the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to theme the imagecache function and add a link the original there.

See:
http://api.lullabot.com/theme_imagecache

And:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_image/6

Comment: Thanks for replying but it didn't take me any further. I've tried many of those variables but I get nothing.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Pretty easy really. CCK already has a filter to display url path, so I wrote in the <a href="<?php print $node->field_gallery_image[0]['filepath']?>>View full size</a>

Comment: That will work. YOu could also use the l() function. Always program to an interface, not an implementation! - l('View full size', base_path() . $node->field_gallery_image[0]['filepath'])

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I can't get that function to work. It prints the base_path two times, don't know why.